# Parts of the UI keep disappearing in a Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app called Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). While using Postman on a Macbook with a retina display, a weird problem keeps cropping up.

Sometimes (about 1 in 20 clicks), clicking on a UI element makes half the UI vanish. The 'Elements' tab of dev tools shows the correct structure - all the divs are there, with display: block. They're just not rendered. Resizing the window by a tiny amount forces a redraw, and all elements become visible again. (I'm currently using Chrome v 37.0.2062.94)

There are no errors printed in the console.

So far, this issue has only been reported on Macbooks with a retina display. I've reproduced this on Canary as well.

Screenshots:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1365493/4188877/06d8b6bc-3777-11e4-8c6b-3f23edfa7c5b.png
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/681190/4188491/1c8f99a2-3773-11e4-8cc9-bbd5d3165530.png

Comment: This sounds like a Chrome bug, so nothing Stack Overflow can help with. I suggest going to https://crbug.com

Comment: I've already posted a bug there. Just wanted to know if anyone has faced a similar issue and found a solution. This problem is "solved" by forcing a resize every time a UI element is clicked, but that's a horrible user experience.

Comment: Please add the link to the bug to the question, or at least in comments, and vice versa (link to this question in bug comments)

Comment: Chromium bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=412299

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We went through all elements that had `overflow: scroll;` and added `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to force better hardware acceleration on those elements.

That fixed the problem. Full detail is posted at http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2015/01/23/ui-repaint-issue-on-chrome/

To sum it up - the issue seems to be around GPU-composting of scrolling elements (when scrollbar occupied right padding) in very high resolutions.

Comment: Looks like the bug to track that is now https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437905 and it's looking to be fixed in the next couple of versions. Can you test it on Canary?