# Chrome print preview redraw issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Currently having an issue with a couple of our sites when using the Google Chrome print preview. This issue is intermittent, where it doesn't render all of the content for the preview. The issue is present when printing as well.

It seems as though it's some type of redrawing issue. What I mean by this is although when the preview initially loads it is missing content, I can fix it by selecting or un-selecting some of the print options. It looks like it forces the preview window to reload and is then all fine.

This of course is not really a solution for our users.

I am using chrome 46.0.2490.80 m on Windows 10. Another colleague is experiencing the same issue on a separate site, using the same version of Chrome on Windows 8.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Does anyone have a fix?

**Addition info**

- Our print stylesheet is separate from the main stylesheet and is individually linked to the document
- We are using bootstrap, which has some print styles of its' own
- Chrome print emulation does not have this issue, it is localized to the print preview.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I have been asked to provide the print stylesheet. I would like to reiterate that this issue isn't localised to a single website or environment. The only common denominator is Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m.

Regardless, here are the print styles:

```
* {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

a,
a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}

abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
}

/*
    * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
    */

.ir a:after,
a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
a[href^="#"]:after {
    content: "";
}

pre,
blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

thead {
    display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
}

tr,
img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

@page {
    margin: 0.5cm;
}

p,
h2,
h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
}

h2,
h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

/*============================================================*\
        $Custom element removal
\*============================================================*/

#main-template,
.footer-cols,
.widget-promo,
.testimonials .column-sidebar,
.widget-range,
.tabs-nav,
.tabs-cnt,
.search-option,
.desktop-hidden,
.shopping-cart .sidebar,
.shopping-cart .legal {display: none;visibility: hidden;}

.widget-video,
.widget-gallery,
.testimonial {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.single-image:after {
    content: ""!important;
}

.t-quote {
    border:none;
}

.retailers .map {height: 600px;}

.print-logo {display: block;visibility: visible;}

nav {display: none;}

.utilities p {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}

.contact-us {display: none;}
```

Comment: Can you share / add your print stylesheet to the question? This will help in identifying the issue. Thanks

Comment: Print styles have been added to the question

Comment: How are you adding your print style to the page? Are you setting using @media print or are you using a separate css print only file (<link>)?

Comment: Our print stylesheet is separate from the main stylesheet and is individually linked to the document

Comment: Hmm not sure how to help without being able to reproduce the issue. Anyway you can set up a [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that showcases the print issue so we can see what is going on?

Comment: No I can't. I have stated that the problem is intermittent. If I was able to reproduce the issue, I'd likely be able to figure out the issue myself.

Comment: What sort of content is missing? Just a few words here and there, whole paragraphs, entire pages, specific HTML elements, non-text features such as borders, backgrounds or images? The possible causes could be totally different depending on what's missing. Other details could also be important, e.g. if other content is moving into the void left by the missing content, that would be a different problem than if, say, the content is getting cut off along the edge of the page but the layout is unaffected. Also, if changing the print settings fixes the problem, what happens if you change them back?

Comment: I think a before/after screenshot might be more informative than your stylesheet, at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I have seen that Chrome print preview having issues when operating with items in stylesheets that are slow to process. The worst being @font import for web-fonts, recommended to be replaced in print or preview stylesheets with the standard fonts. Whilst these do not appear in your stylesheet above  (thank you for adding this by the way), the * and ^ selectors you have in the css do trigger warnings for being slow and should be avoided anyway. I use [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) for checking, not sure how much this helps, but it could be worth starting from a basic css to check what happens and then build up from there.

Answer (score 1):

Could be hardware acceleration issue as stated on this website 
http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/01/23/ui-repaint-issue-on-chrome/

> We went through all elements that had overflow: scroll; and added
>   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to force better hardware acceleration on those elements.

Could also be similar problem of this >
[Parts of the UI keep disappearing in a Chrome app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757453/parts-of-the-ui-keep-disappearing-in-a-chrome-app)